# material UI CardHeader action drop-down

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add a FormControl, a Select component and a MenuItem to the action prop of the CardHeader IconButton.

Currently the code looks like this:

Rendering:

```
<CardHeader
  action={
    <IconButton
      onClick={this.renderFilterRequest()}
    >
      <Edit />
    </IconButton>
    }
/>
```

onClick method:

```
renderFilterRequest() {
  const { selection } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl>
        <Select
          value={selection}
          onChange={this.handleFilterChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value='1'>January</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value='2'>February</MenuItem>

        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The error I get is `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type. What is the right way to render the dropdown menu on CardHeader action click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning some div from from `this.renderFilterRequest`, And you are also calling the function, so the value of `onClick` becomes the div. But they were meant to be functions, right?

So it should have been just: `onClick={this.renderFilterRequest}`.
This function also returned a div but there is no way to attach it to rendering logic in `render`.

You need to put the MenuItems in your render method and show/hide them depending on the state.

Your onClick listener should be a function that changes the state so that the MenuItems become visible.

Here is a simple demo how this should be done:

[image: Edit Material demo]